# Generic function accepting &str or moving String without copying

Tags: generics, rust, ownership-semantics

I want to write a generic function that accepts any kind of string (`&str`/`String`) for convenience of the caller.

The function internally needs a `String`, so I'd also like to avoid needless re-allocation if the caller calls the function with `String`.

```
foo("borrowed");
foo(format!("owned"));
```

For accepting references I know I can use `foo<S: AsRef<str>>(s: S)`, but what about the other way?

I think generic argument based on `ToOwned` might work (works for `&str`, and I'm assuming it's a no-op on `String`), but I can't figure out the exact syntax.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think what you are after can be achieved with the [`Into` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html), like this:

```
fn foo<S: Into<String>>(s: S) -> String {
    return s.into();
}

fn main () {
    foo("borrowed");
    foo(format!("owned"));
}
```